# Concatenate different sass files to corresponding css files

Tags: brunch

In my `app/styles/` directory I have the following files

- application_blue.scss

  application_red.scss

I'd like to concatenate those files into `public/stylesheets/application_blue.css` and `public/stylesheets/application_red.css` respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stylesheets:
  defaultExtension: 'scss'
  joinTo: 
    'stylesheets/application_blue.css': /^app\/styles\/application_blue/
    'stylesheets/application_red.css': /^app\/styles\/application_red/
```

Okay I found the solution, might help others